# Printing array of primitives in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, primitive-types

I've got two arrays:

```
char[] chars = { '1', '2', '3' };
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Why after calling `System.out.print(chars)` I'm getting `123` while after `System.out.print(numbers)` I've got smth like `[C@9304b1` ?

What is more, after printing `System.out.print("abc" + chars)` I'm also getting `abc[C@9304b1` .

I know that `[C@9304b1` equals chars.toString() method but why sometimes System.out.print print only its elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PrintStream`, the type of `System.out`, has several overloads for the `print` method, one of which takes an array of characters (`char[]`):

> [`public void print(char[] s)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29)
>
> > Prints an array of characters. The
> >     characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's
> >     default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the
> >     manner of the write(int) method.

Thus, in your first example, you get `123` printed. However, `PrintStream` doesn't have an overload for `print` that can accept an `int[]` as an argument, thus, you end up invoking [`print(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29), which will use the `toString` method of an `Object`, consisting of its type and its hashcode.

In order to print an `int[]`, you can use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default toString() just prints out a default "here's what/where this object is", and different types do different things.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that System.out.print can accept a char array and convert it into printable text, thus giving the string "123", but the array of integers does not have an implicit method to display itself as text, so it just displays the address of the array.